# Picking training data

Tags: machine-learning, training

Suppose i want to have 80% training data and 20% testing data. How do i choose which 80% of the data to use for training? Should it be completely random? Like what if there is a class label with 2 clusters and the 80% training data we randomly choose only captures one of the clusters?

Comment: use train_test_split of sklearn, it shuffles and splits

Answer (score 2):

In order to validation you can choose different methods such as `k-fold cross validation`, `repeated splits` and `Bootstrapping`. It seems what you aim to do is 2 fold cross validation and yes it should be random. You should be careful, and it seems your training data and testing data are very different.In this case, you;ll not have a model with a good performance.Try to find a way and make your training data look more like the data on which you want to implement your model. In this case you might want try 10 fold cross validation (for instance)